# How to get the logged in user accountname using Windows Web Service?

Tags: windows-services

We have 10 computers and 1 server.

Our webservice runs as LOCALSYSTEM every computer.

The webservice has code that writes to a file on the central server machine.

The service has timer with duration of 30mins. Every 30 mins a different user logs into the system. We want the service to detect the name of the current logged in user and pass to the method that writes to notepad..

Question is how to get the loged in user name?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract all information about current user sessions using [Remote Desktop Services API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383464(v=vs.85).aspx) on Windows. There is a simple way to enumerate all sessions with [WTSEnumerateSessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383833(v=vs.85).aspx), however a better way for your system service would be to subscribe to notifications about session changes and receive SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE events inside your service' [HandleEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683241(v=vs.85).aspx) procedure.

Either way (direct enumeration of sessions or session events) you will get a session ID that you can use to call [WTSQuerySessionInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383838(v=vs.85).aspx), passing WTSUserName as a third parameter to the function. This will give you a required user name back in the buffer.